# ESLint not finding files

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I've been trying to lint my new project with ESLint without any luck. Previously, running `yarn eslint --fix .`, would lint all the files in my project, but now, it gives this error: `No files matching the pattern "." were found.`. Was there a breaking change?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [relevant github issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10599)

TLDR: run `yarn eslint --fix '.'`